# Heroku phone number additional verification for addons

Tags: heroku, verification

Have heroku free plan. Can't verify with russian phone number. Tried to verify through several USA temp phone, heroku has sent, but i didn't get code. Any ideas, how can i verify my account? And can i verify it with free plan?
p.s. wanna install SendGrid

Comment: Shouldn't you ask customer support for this?

Comment: Can't do that using free plan

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is 2FA Authentication. This requires a phone. But by doing so you won't be able to install `SendGrid`.

For that you need a verified account. This is not done by a phone number.

Heroku has an article about Verification: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification

Basically you need a credit card.

Most addons (including the free ones) require a credit card verified account.

Comment: Already set credit card without any problems. But phone number verification is still needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was only solved for me through support ticket on Heroku. Someone from their support team manually verified the account.